# Internal Server Error issue with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have issue with my .htaccess
here it's content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /repo/repo1
RewriteRule ^(Packages.*|Release.*|.+\.deb|CydiaIcon\.png|uploads\/[^\/]+|[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?\.bz2)$ admin/api/rewrite.php?file=$1
RewriteRule ^(debs|depiction|stats)\/?(.*)$ admin/$1/$2
IndexIgnore *
php_value auto_append_file none
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
```

it give me this error

**`Internal Server Error`**

but when i delete it
my page works fine

i think there are issue with syntax but i cannot figure it :(
Any Suggest ?

**EDIT**
My error log

```
[Tue Sep 16 13:11:54 2014] [error] [client 79.82.250.27] File does not exist: /home/idevteam/public_html/betarepo/500.shtml
[Tue Sep 16 13:11:54 2014] [alert] [client 79.82.250.27] /home/idevteam/public_html/betarepo/repo/repo1/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(Packages.*|Release.*|.+\\.deb|CydiaIcon\\.png|uploads)\\/[^\\/]+|[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?\\.bz2)$'
```

Comment: what does your error logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant part of your error:

> RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(Packages.*|Release.*|.+\.deb|CydiaIcon\.png|uploads)\/[^\/]+|[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?\.bz2)$'

There's a few things wrong here. Although this isn't what's causing your error, you probably don't want those double backslashes (which means you literally want to match a backslash) because you want to escape the `.`'s instead:

`^(Packages.*|Release.*|.+\.deb|CydiaIcon\.png|uploads)\/[^\/]+|[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?\.bz2)$`

Next thing, and this is probably causing the error, you've got mismatched parentheses. The last `)` doesn't match anything. You probably want an open parent right after the first `/`, making an optional "or" using the next `|`:

`^(Packages.*|Release.*|.+\.deb|CydiaIcon\.png|uploads)\/([^\/]+|[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?\.bz2)$`

Comment: Thank, but i have this issus now `[Tue Sep 16 13:22:12 2014] [error] [client 79.82.250.27] File does not exist: /home/idevteam/public_html/betarepo/500.shtml
[Tue Sep 16 13:22:12 2014] [alert] [client 79.82.250.27] /home/idevteam/public_html/betarepo/repo/repo1/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: Fixed by commenting php_value :'(

Answer (score 0):

I found wraping it like this worked for me:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
</IfModule>
```